# Cloudwatch agent gives an error unable to open database file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm having this issue with *awslogs* services.
Here is my awslogs.conf
[image: awslogs.conf]

And when i tail the /var/log/awslogs.log I'm getting this error. I have no idea why this is happening. I'm using IAM ROLE and it has been attached to EC2 Instance. 
[image: giv]

Comment: Is the agent operating under a user that has permission to access `/var/awslogs/state`? See: [AWS Developer Forums: "unable to open database file" in ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=165134)

Comment: Please edit your question to insert the information as TEXT rather than graphics, so that it becomes searchable.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein issue was sorted. Thanks 
I change awslogs.conf file 
[general]
/var/awslogs/state/agent-state